# Cookiecutter: how do you override a dictionary variable using the command-line?

Tags: cookiecutter

If I have variables in `cookiecutter.json` like so:

```json
{
    "app": {
        "name": "myapp",
        "description": "my app description",
        "version": "v1",
        "ecr_data_classification_tag": "non-pii"
    },
    "contact": {
        "team": "monitors",
        "name": "WS Monitors",
        "url": "http://myurl.tld/"
    },
    "etc": "foo"
}
```

How do I override the app `name` when invoking cookiecutter?

I've tried supplying the "extra context" this way:

```
$ cookiecutter --no-input my-template app.name="my-new-name"
```

and:

```
$ cookiecutter --no-input my-template app='{"name":"my-new-name"}'
```

but the former does nothing and the latter just replaces the entire `app` parameter with the string `{\"name\":\"my-new-name\"}` (it doesn't parse the JSON).

I tried dumping the whole thing into a yaml file, and that works:

```yaml
default_context:
  app:
    name: my-new-name
```

but that's not ideal. It also wipes out all the other `app` parameters.

Is there a way to invoke cookiecutter from the command-line and *just* override `app.name`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that:

1. No, the "extra context" is just k/v pairs, and the key and value are not parsed at all
2. As of 2.1.1, when the value is swapped in to override the config, [the entire value is swapped](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/blob/2.1.1/cookiecutter/generate.py#L73), so for dictionaries/objects, there's no way to replace just an attribute of the value, you have to replace the entire value.
3. [`cksak` made a change](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/blob/main/cookiecutter/generate.py#L74) to walk the dictionaries and only swap out the specified values, but that's in `main` and hasn't been released yet

So, for now, if you want to override dictionary values you have no choice but to create a separate yaml (or json) file and load that via `--config-file`, and until 2.1.2 is released, you will have to make sure you override *all* of the attributes of each dictionary unless you want them wiped out.

Comment: Do you know if this has been released now?

Comment: It has. I have not validated the functionality, but the code has definitely been released.